# Where to insert 'orderby' expression in this linq-to-sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

```
var result = db.PhotoAlbums.Select(albums => new PhotoAlbumDisplay
            {
                AlbumID = albums.AlbumID,
                Title = albums.Title,
                Date = albums.Date,
                PhotoID = albums.Photos.Select(photo => photo.PhotoID).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
            });
```

Wherever I try to put `orderby albums.AlbumID descending` I get error. Someone knows solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = db.PhotoAlbums.Select(albums => new PhotoAlbumDisplay
            {
                AlbumID = albums.AlbumID,
                Title = albums.Title,
                Date = albums.Date,
                PhotoID = albums.Photos.Select(photo => photo.PhotoID).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
            })
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.AlbumID);
```

In query syntax:

```
var result = from albums in db.PhotoAlbums
             orderby albums.AlbumID descending
             select new PhotoAlbumDisplay
             {
                 AlbumID = albums.AlbumID,
                 Title = albums.Title,
                 Date = albums.Date,
                 PhotoID = albums.Photos.Select(photo => photo.PhotoID).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
            };
```

Comment: It works... and this other query version is just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the query syntax, you'll have to start with "from X select" and work from that. In this case it'd be easier to just use the .OrderBy() method to order the results.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var result = db.PhotoAlbums.Select(albums => new PhotoAlbumDisplay
        {
            AlbumID = albums.AlbumID,
            Title = albums.Title,
            Date = albums.Date,
            PhotoID = albums.Photos.Select(photo => photo.PhotoID).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
        })
        .OrderByDescending(a=>a.AlbumID);
```

Comment: yep... Ahmad already gave me answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556378/where-to-insert-orderby-expression-in-this-linq-to-sql-query/2556397#2556397 ...thanks!